# elementor background video not playing

Tags: wordpress, html5-video, elementor

On a website I'm working on - https://bi-impro.si - on the front page there is a gif background image you can see when you access the website. That gif is a big file, so I converted it to .mp4, uploaded the video, in elementor chose the video background option, and pasted the link to the video (https://bi-impro.si/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/prstki_mp4.mp4). But the video does not load when I test the website, it just shows the grey area. I added the "background fallback" option of a mentioned gif image, but I want to use the .mp4 image file because it loads faster.

---

If I see correctly, in page source code there are these lines:

```
<section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-afa0f47 elementor-section-height-min-height elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-items-middle" data-id="afa0f47" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;video&quot;,&quot;background_video_link&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/bi-impro.si\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/12\/prstki_mp4.mp4&quot;,&quot;background_video_start&quot;:0,&quot;background_video_end&quot;:10,&quot;background_play_on_mobile&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_play_once&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;}">
                                <div class="elementor-background-video-container">
                                                    <video class="elementor-background-video-hosted elementor-html5-video" autoplay muted playsinline></video>
                                            </div>
                                    <div class="elementor-background-overlay"></div>
```

But I see no problem with that code. I'm not a web programmer, I just use Elementor to build this website.

Comment: Is it fixed now? Works okay for me in Chrome/Windows (I see MP4 video as background)...

Comment: @VC.One It's not. If I remove the background fallback gif, it shows grey area with no image or video.

Comment: Using the following will show background MP4 (must hide GIF) : `<video class="elementor-background-video-hosted elementor-html5-video" autoplay muted playsinline loop src="https://bi-impro.si/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/prstki_mp4.mp4"></video>` ...Is it getting closer to your expected result?

Comment: PS: Also I see you have `data-settings=` and is the video URL supposed to be extracted from there? Maybe try replacing all `&quot;` with `\"` to get it responding (_ie:_ providing a readable URL)...

Comment: @VC.One I'm using the Elementor plugin, it is creating a code on its own. I don't think I can edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

On the particular page, you want to add the video, you'll notice there's no src attribute, that's why there's no video.....

Temporary fix, add a script tag on the page and add this.... with "xyz.mp4" = video name

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>{
    document.querySelector('#intro-video video').src = "xyz.mp4;
})
```